# Need help replacing subqueries with window functions in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns the results I want, however it takes 3 full table scans because of the subqueries. My attempts to turn this into window functions have not worked. Thoughts?

```
SELECT a_day
    ,max(week_count)
    ,max(month_count)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('day', created_at) AS a_day
        ,(
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM accounts AS wk
            WHERE wk.created_at BETWEEN (a.created_at - INTERVAL '7 days')
                    AND a.created_at
            ) AS week_count
        ,(
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM accounts AS wk
            WHERE wk.created_at BETWEEN (a.created_at - INTERVAL '30 days')
                    AND a.created_at
            ) AS month_count
    FROM accounts a
    ORDER BY a_day
    ) AS sub_1
GROUP BY a_day
ORDER BY a_day
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what this query is supposed to do? The innermost queries obviously count the number of accounts in the 7 or 30 days prior to `created_at`, but then how can you have multiple counts at a single date so that you can `GROUP BY` it in the main query?

Comment: In the accounts table, there can be multiple accounts created in one day. I'd like to return one row for each day that has at least one account created along with a count of the number of accounts from the previous 7 and 30 days. Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured.But then it seems the query *as is* can be greatly simplified by doing the counts for 7 and 30 days on the date (after `date_trunc()` therefore), not on the timestamp so you will not need the outermost aggregation.

Comment: I *really* like the idea of making the query simpler, but I thought subqueries could only return one value. Seems like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with sub_1 as
(select date_trunc('day', created_at) AS a_day, count(*) as week_count
 from accounts
 where created_at BETWEEN (created_at - INTERVAL '7 days') and created_at
 group by date_trunc('day', created_at))
,sub_2 as 
(select date_trunc('day', created_at) AS a_day, count(*) as month_count
 from accounts
 where created_at BETWEEN (created_at - INTERVAL '30 days') and created_at
 group by date_trunc('day', created_at))
 select sub_1.a_day, max(sub_1.week_count), max(sub_2.month_count)
 from sub_1 join sub_2 on sub_1.a_day = sub_2.a_day
 group by sub_1.a_day
```

Try using the Common table expressions and see if you can get the performance gain. This scans the table 2 times instead of 3.

Comment: Agree 2 table scans are better than three :-) In my small scale tests, the execution time went from 300 ms to 10 ms.